# Select rows from a dataframe where a column does not take one of the values in a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a list of values that is a subset of all values that a specific column can take:

```
list1=['DHL','FDX','UPS','USPS','Others']
```

Based on the value of the shipping company used for a shipment, I can choose rows (for example):

```
df2=df1[df1['ShippingCompany']=='DHL']
```

Now, I need to select 'Others', where rows correspond to all shipping companies other than the one listed before 'Others'. How do I do this without having to write a long chain? Mind you, list1 contents can change between invocations, where customers can add other values before 'Others'.

I am thinking of the following metacode:

```
df2=df1[df1['ShippingCompany'] is not in list1[:-1]]
```

Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `isin` or `==`

```
df2=df1[df1['ShippingCompany'] == list1[-1]]
```

More than two value

```
df2=df1[~df1['ShippingCompany'].isin(list1[:-1])]
```